# Stop the server using batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file

Can we stop servers using batch file?

I am using Weblogic (v10) application server.
I want to stop the server or kill the process using batch file.
my application contains three Weblogic instances(Admin Server, Application Server ,Registration Server).

Please tell me how can we stop servers using batch file?

Comment: "Can we stop servers using batch file?"------------ yes

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's possible to script all interactions with WebLogic instances, so my guess is "yes", it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
I think iv just found it on Google.

See [Starting / Stopping WebLogic Server](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/web/bea_weblogic/812/StartingStoppingWebLogicServer.shtml) and notice that you will need to first setup your environment to use the Command-line Commands.